# Phonegap CDVViewController.h file not found when Archiving for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I'm currently using Phonegap 2.0 to develop an iOS App in XCode. The app builds and runs fine in the emulator and also on the testing devices.

The problem appears when I try to archive the app for distribution. The archive fails with the following message:

CDVViewController.h file not found.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

**Xcode 6.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

**Xcode 7.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

1.Double click the `<multiple values>` and you can add this in.

2.Change `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include` to `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include`

[image]

Answer (score 33):

On **Xcode 7.1**, you would need to update **`header search paths`** field from `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include` to `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include`

You can find **`header search paths`** under **`build settings`** -> **`search paths`**

Answer (score 10):

Managed to fix it.

These were missing from "Header Search Path" in the build setting of my TARGET settings:

```
"$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"
"$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)"
```

Get the solution form multiple sources:

Upgrading Cordova iOS (Stepts from 31) http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_upgrading_ios_index.md.html#Upgrading%20Cordova%20iOS

Bug report https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1122

Discussion at groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/IcR8-ijrUfk

Discussion at groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/PzqZEm8QKmc

Answer (score 6):

For future ref:

I just fixed this exact problem for myself.

If you are using Cordova cli, and have your config.xml updated, you can just remove ios as a platform and add it back. Then archive again from XCode.

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Hope that helps, worked perfectly for me,

Comment: I confirm this did it for me. Only I didn't do it directly using Cordova but through Meteor with: `meteor remove-platform ios` and then `meteor add-platform ios`

Comment: I do not use XCode to develop my phonegap app, this worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing the exact same problem.  I believe it may have been introduced because I moved the location of the Xcode project after I created it with Cordova's tools.  Or, it may also be possible that I didn't properly setup the Cordova iOS toolset - perhaps I didn't run the installer package (I've rebuilt this machine a couple of times).  Also, all the related answers I found with Google suggested I needed to change some of Cordova's core classes - which I wasn't willing to do.

My solution was to use the Cordova `create` command to build an entirely new Xcode project.  I copied my original project's `www` directory into the new project and then went about re-configuring the new project to match the settings of the original project.

The new project, using the same plugins, frameworks and build settings successfully built an archive whereas the original project could not.  It's not an ideal solution - but it worked.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do that. That's exactly what I ended up doing and it worked. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue when copying my project to another folder.
I'm using Phonegap 2.0.0.
After trying several solutions without success, I ran Product->Clean and everything worked properly.
Do not ask me why but this path already solved several small glitches that I had to deal with, i.e. changing splash and icon files, who was not updated on device.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

As is sometimes the case, an accepted solution may not help everyone with a similar but perhaps unrelated issue.

My observation was similar (CDVViewController.h not found). First ensure the TARGET settings includes "header search paths" as described above.

Then follow this link to what worked for me: http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/

Essentially I needed to re-link cordova as a target dependency and then Link it to my libraries.

THEN, If you migrated to cordova 2.5.0, you will likely run into an issue that spits out something similar to this:
""_ALAssetPropertyDate", referenced from:

```
  ___23-[CDVFile getMetadata:]_block_invoke in libCordova.a(CDVFile.o)

  ___27-[CDVFile getFileMetadata:]_block_invoke in libCordova.a(CDVFile.o)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_ALAssetsLibrary", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in libCordova.a(CDVFile.o)

  objc-class-ref in libCordova.a(CDVFileTransfer.o)

  objc-class-ref in libCordova.a(CDVURLProtocol.o)
```

"

If os, add the AssetLibrary framework and have some peace.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that it is "header search paths" in TARGET settings, not project.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
```

Adding this to the "Search Paths" section in "Build Settings" work perfectly.

[Search Paths in XCode Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64mRR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your CordovaLib sub-project reference.

Launch Terminal
Go to the location where you installed Cordova in the bin sub-folder. For example, `/Users/Shared/Cordova/phonegap-2.2.0/lib/ios/bin`

Run the command below where the first parameter is the path to your project's .xcodeproj file:

```
./update_cordova_subproject /path/to/your/project
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 7.2 is a little different

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
```

needs to be put in the header search paths for debug and for release.

[image: Header search paths have a debug and release sub field]