# How to install phoneGap in an exisitng Xcode project

Tags: iphone, cordova

I have already built an Xcode project without phoneGap, but the client wants to add some new functionality. So I decided to use phoneGap to do it, I don't know how to import phoneGap to my old Xcode project. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can embed a cordova webview in any ios project following this steps: (Steps for cordova version < 2.3, in 2.3 its a bit different, see the link below)

> Adding Cleaver to your Xcode project (CordovaLib sub-project)

```
Install Cordova
Copy the Cordova.plist file into your project folder on disk
Drag and drop the Cordova.plist file into the Project Navigator of Xcode
Choose the radio-button "Create groups for any added folders"
Press the key combination Option-Command-A, which should drop down a sheet to add files to your project (the "Add Files..." sheet). Make sure the "Created groups for any added folders" radio-button is selected
Press the key combination Shift-Command-G, which should drop down another sheet for you to go to a folder (the "Go to the folder:" sheet)
Enter ~/Documents/CordovaLib/ in the "Go to the folder:" sheet and then press the "Go" button
Select the VERSION file in the the "Add Files..." sheet
Press the "Add" button in the "Add Files..." sheet
Press the key combination Option-Command-A, which should drop down a sheet to add files to your project (the "Add Files..." sheet). Make sure the "Created groups for any added folders" radio-button is selected
Press the key combination Shift-Command-G, which should drop down another sheet for you to go to a folder (the "Go to the folder:" sheet)
Enter ~/Documents/CordovaLib/CordovaLib.xcodeproj in the "Go to the folder:" sheet and then press the "Go" button
Press the "Add" button in the "Add Files..." sheet
Select CordovaLib.xcodeproj in the Project Navigator
Press the key combination Option-Command-1 to show the File Inspector
Choose "Relative to CORDOVALIB" in the File Inspector for the drop-down menu for Location
Click on the project icon in the Project Navigator, select your Project, then select the "Build Settings" tab
Add -all_load and -Obj-C - for the "Other Linker Flags" value
Click on the project icon in the Project Navigator, select your Target, then select the "Build Phases" tab
Expand "Link Binaries with Libraries"

Click on the "+" button, and add these frameworks (and optionally in the Project Navigator, move them under the Frameworks group):

AddressBook.framework
AddressBookUI.framework
AudioToolbox.framework
AVFoundation.framework
CoreLocation.framework
MediaPlayer.framework
QuartzCore.framework
SystemConfiguration.framework
MobileCoreServices.framework
CoreMedia.framework

Expand "Target Dependencies" - the top box labeled like this if you have multiple boxes!
Click on the "+" button, and add the CordovaLib build product
Expand "Link Binaries with Libraries" - the top box labeled like this if you have multiple boxes!
Click on the "+" button, and add libCordova.a
```

for more info

[phonegap cleaver < 2.3.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS)

[phonegap cleaver >= 2.3.0](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS)

Comment: i got this error "[__NSCFDictionary dictionaryWithLowercaseKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xbeb3da0" any idea for this ????

Comment: which phonegap version did you install? I have seen that problem in this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/z5MrloZGol4

Comment: Thanks for you help .. i fix that problem.

Comment: i can install phonegap on my xcode project and run well, but i cannt Archive it.. the error is "Cordova/CDVViewController.h" not found .. can you help me ?

Comment: @Allan.Chen I have faced same problem while Archiving. how do you solve it?

Comment: @NSEncoder Check this guy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios/12596916#comment18250311_12596916

Comment: Unable to build the project. It gives "Build Failed" and "No issues". Its not listing any errors. How to find the error?