# How to wrap existing iOS application with PhoneGap

Tags: android, iphone, ios, cordova

I already have working iPhone & Android application. We are planning to add more features/pages and we're also planing to extend the application with PhoneGap to support multiple mobile platform.

How I can utilize PhoneGap with my existing iPhone application? Whether PhoneGap is plugable, is there any other idea otherthan rewriting the entire Application with PhoneGap?

Comment: We can add Corodova in any existing ios Project. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420426/how-to-install-phonegap-in-an-exisitng-xcode-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never personally used phonegap, but couldnt you just add in the phonegap sdk, and just use a webview in any activities/view controllers that you add?  That way you can keep all your old ones the same, but add new ones that will be the same for ios and android.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. Your best bet is to re-write the application using PhoneGap.

Comment: Can't we add the PhoneGap SDK and use it?

Comment: I've not heard of this ever being done. Anything is possible with time & effort, but it is not a task I would sign up for. Phonegap wasn't built for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use PhoneGap with a webView, in your existing project.

See [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS) link.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, what you're asking for is not possible or at least -- not reasonable.

If I'm getting you right, you have written a *native* mobile applications for iOS (in ObjC) and Android (in Java) whereas Phonegap applications are HTML5-based applications embed in their own container.

These are two completely different worlds with no (useful or profitable) way of mixing them.

You can consider some tricks (with webview, as mentioned in other answers) to include *new code*, written in Phonegap in your *existing* native applications. But, there is no chance, you can reuse *native* code (i.e. current functionality) inside Phonegap.

The only thing, I can think of is, that you can consider proting existing applications as native plugins and using inside Phonegap. But, you will require a lot of work to change existing code to fit plugins' standards and I'm not sure, if rewriting entire application from scratch in Phonegap wouldn't be better solution, as in terms of time and money spent on this process.