# PhoneGap Xcode Missing Header files on Build 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am using PhoneGap 2.2.0 and XCode 4.5.2.

I can test my programs in the simulators, and I can put them on my devices to test them.

But I simply cannot build for distribution. It always fails with the following error:

my-projevt-path/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

I've seen this problem around the web and still can't make it work, given whatever solutions have been posted.

I've changed things in Build Settings, I've  reinstalled PhoneGap, I've run new lines in terminal, I've done my app over starting a new PhoneGap project from scratch, I've checked preferences in the build location in Xcode... I can't figure this out AT ALL.

Please, can anyone help? I've been working on this for days.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be happening only on builds when I try to sign the code. But as far as I can tell, my provisioning and distribution certificates are all set up right.

Comment: check this link [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios/12596916#12596916

Answer (score 1):

Problems in Xcode

If you have compilation problems related to missing headers, the build products should build into the same build directory. You may need to set the preference "Xcode Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data -> Advanced…" to "Unique". This is the default setting for Xcode on a fresh new install, if you upgraded from older versions of Xcode, you might have a legacy preference in there that you need to update.

Found the answer!!!

Comment: Thanks for the input, George. Unfortunately, I had seen this solution already and it is not the cause of my problem. My preferences are and always have been set to "Unique." So, something else is causing the problem. Anything else I need to know about getting the settings right to "build into the same build directory?"

Comment: Did you read about how you have to update the library path ?,using ./updatecordovalibpath or something like that. after creating the project? also are all your folders accessible with the right permissions?

Comment: This worked for me. I had just upgraded from XCode 8.0 to 8.1. First install of ionic. Had this problem. Solution above fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am getting the same problem yeah and some help could be great.....
I followed all the instructions even with the ./update_cordova_subproject path as well it does not work. Also I solved the locking problem but I could not find the solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer, in my case, had seemingly nothing to do with the error message that was being sent. Missing header files? That didn't seem to be the issue. Or, at least, not the direct cause of the issue.

This was an issue with my provisioning/certificates being somehow not right. I had re-created them several times, but it continued to be an issue.

I sent the job to another developer, who opened it on his machine, revoked my certificates and created new ones, and built it without changing anything else. He forwarded me the certificate, the provisioning, and an archive of the job. I opened the archive in xCode and validated it and uploaded it. And it was fine.

If you have got this problem, be certain your certificate/provisioning is set up right. I thought mine was, but apparently it wasn't?  The "Apple Process" is definitely weird, and when certificates / profiles gets messed up, problems arise.

Comment: One further comment... upon speaking with the other developer, I came to realize that he, too, had "some problems" with a more modern version of PhoneGap/Cordova and was forced to use an old 1.x version of PhoneGap, at which point there were no problems. So, it may, in fact be a combination of factors.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and just solved it! First of the problem may very well be because of your distribution provisioning files... but when you look at the Project Navigator in xCode at the top level you have your Project and inside you have the **CordovaLib.xcodeproj** click on this file and you will see the iOS Deployment target. Make sure the proper IOS version is selected there. This is 1/2.

2) Then you need to duplicate the Release configuration and rename it **Distribution**. While the CordovaLib.xcodeproj is selected make a build and then build the actual project. This worked smoothly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths`:

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
```

Don't replace the existing line that looks similar, that is still needed to be backwards compatible with Xcode 7 and Xcode 6.4.