# Cordova header file missing while integrating PhoneGap application in Jenkins

Tags: iphone, ios7, jenkins, cordova-2.0.0

I am trying to integrate a PhoneGap application with Jenkins, but i am getting some error messages in jenkins (and also in Terminal) as the Cordova files has not been found, but in XCode I am not getting any errors

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/appName/workspace/appName/Plugins/WebAppPlugin.h:9:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVPlugin.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVPlugin.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/appName/workspace/appName/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
        ^
1 error generated.
```

I tried many solutions from previous posts, nothing helps

Solution 1: ["'CDVPlugin.h' file not found" in Cordova as component (Cleaver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714600/cdvplugin-h-file-not-found-in-cordova-as-component-cleaver)

solution 2: ['Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found when run in Xcode terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728714/cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-run-in-xcode-terminal#)

Solution 3: [PhoneGap Xcode Missing Header files on Build 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460432/phonegap-xcode-missing-header-files-on-build-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file?rq=1)

Solution 4: [still getting <Cordova/CDVViewController.h> file not found error in xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445556/still-getting-cordova-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-error-in-xcode?rq=1)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios