# PhoneGap 2.1.0 iOS Mac Xcode CordovaLib

Tags: xcode, cordova

Trying to get some solid documentation on how to get the iPhone emulator in Xcode running with my PhoneGap 2.1.0 project. I pulled it down from a git repo that I originally built on my Mac Pro, now want to run it on my Mac Air. There is a lot of confusion of the terminologies between PhoneGap and Cordova that make it near impossible for a beginner to figure out how to set up a project.

The problem I'm getting when I open my PhoneGap project in XCode is this error:

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
```

Clearly the Cordova class files aren't being seen by XCode, although I included the path to the CordovaLib classes in Preferences -> Source Trees (~/Documents/CordovaLib/.

Just want to get this thing running! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the solutions from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios ?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this will help you, but I am starting to try to get to grips with PhoneGap/Cordova, and found this excellent guide on getting it going.

It uses Cordova, which I am led to believe is the source of PhoneGap (Still SLightly Confused tbh), hopefully it will help you in one way or another, it certainly got me up and running :)

https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDUyNDQxMjA3MzY2NzYzNDU0MjgBMTAxMDE4ODcyODc5Njc4NDQwMzQBOWNxRFF3Z0UyX29KATQBAXYy