# Phonegap CDVViewController.h not found when archiving for distribution

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am experiencing this issue in **version 2.2 of Cordova/Phonegap** in **Xcode 4.5.2**.  This is a **new project** - so right off the bat without anything in the `www` folder modified.  When I build in Debug mode everything goes fine.  When I try to *build for archiving* in distribution mode (AdHoc or App store) I get this error:

```
'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
```

Is there any further information that I can post to help clarify the situation?

I have tried starting from scratch several times (as per the suggestion of some similar questions I've seen asked) as well as uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode for good measure.  My Xcode *derived data* location is set to *Unique* (as per another similar question).  I have also performed `update_cordova_subproject` on the project to no effect.

Thanks so much for any help here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying every solution I could find (including the ones Jonathan posted for this question) with no success I have solved my problem.  Hopefully this answer added to the list of others will help someone else.  If my answer does not apply to your similar situation please check out the list below posted by Jonathan which is a comprehensive list of other possible solutions.

My somewhat unique situation:  In a pre 2.0 version of Phonegap (when I was able to compile) I had created a **custom build configuration** for AdHoc and AppStore.  The defaults we have are "Debug" and "Release" and my two custom configurations were created so I didn't have to switch the code signing certificates when I switched from an AppStore release to an AdHoc build.

The problem/solution:  In post 2.0 Phonegap we've got an instance of CordovaLib.xcodeproj subproject (this is new)... which means if I'm going to use a custom build in my main project I have to add that custom build configuration in this subproject as well.

Project Navigator >> Click CordovaLib.xcodeproj >> Click on the *project* CordovaLib >> Configurations >> make sure whichever build you are going to use exists (by name) in this list.  No further configuration is necessary assuming you've already dealt with this in your main project having created these custom build configurations in the past.

Comment: Note that in XCode 7.1 you need to change it to: "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include"

Answer (score 8):

I had the *same problem* a couple of weeks ago, I did some research in attempts to find the cause and solution to this but ended up trying different approaches and then suddenly and as randomly, it just worked. What exactly made it work - I cannot tell but I would suggest you to **go for a trail and error approach** and try out the following

I've listed the **suggested solutions** below in order of relevance (likelihood to solve your issue) as well as by complexity (ascending)

### Approach 1

Go to **BuildSettings** > **Header** > **Search Paths** and add the following line:

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include
```

More info/suggestions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios/12596916)

### Approach 2

For some reason, it appears as if **the dependencies in Cordova gets missing** when upgrading to a new 2.x version of Cordova. This is assumed to the cause of Cordova 2.x having *changed how the framework* is referenced in iOS projects.
Try following the steps of
[This article](http://outof.me/embedding-cordovalib-in-your-iosphonegap-app-project/)

### Approach 3

If A1 and A2 fails to solve your issue, the error message you receive may be of somewhat misleading nature, forcing one to look at **alternative approaches** to other potential causes. **Certificates** and Code Signing identities would be the next place to look into. Try **removing them from keychain/xcode**, **revoke** them from within the *Provisional Portal*, **recreate** new ones and add them to your Xcode project. Try archiving and see if it works.

### Approach 4

Make sure both your **main project** and the **CordovaLib.xcodeproj** are set to **Build Active Architecture Only**

### Other suggestions

*you may have tried one or more of these but just to make sure*

1. **Re-install cordova** from brand new installation, explicitly install the command line tools on the latest version of Xcode (quit Xcode before doing this)
2. **Copy your old projects www folder** into the new command line created www folder after deleting everything it presently contains
3. Keep an eye on the **error console** when running, see if there's any error that may further help to identify the origins of this issue.

Please let me know if neither of these proposed solutions solved your issue, then we'll just have to **dig deeper until we find a working solution**.

Comment: Jonathan,  thanks so much for the answer.  I had tried all of these solutions individually over the last week and tried them again to no great effect after you posted.  In the process I had a lightbulb moment and solved my problem > see my answer.  This question has become an awesome one stop shop for this problem thanks to you.

Comment: Great, I'm happy you found your solution

Comment: Thanks, I ran into the same Cordova issue and the first approach helped me (with the update from nitzan-wilnai: "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include")

Comment: The approach 4 did the trick. I'm using IBM Mobilefirst Platform 7.0. and I was getting the 'file not found' error.

Answer (score 8):

**Xcode 6.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

**Xcode 7.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

it's work for me . hope it can help you..

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when using Cordova 2.7.0 on xcode 4.6.2 and fixed it by changing the setting for the build location for derived data:

Go to xcode->preferences
Clicked advanced button under derived data
Select unique

The reason I encountered this problem was because I was restarting a new 'version' of an old project as a new project in xcode, and after creating it I changed the bundle identifier to match my old project (Doing this allows you to submit your new project as an update of your old project in the app store).
The default setting for derived data was Legacy, so it was looking for the cordova files using the original bundle identifier, not the new one.

Hope this helps someone that may encounter something similar