# Build fail while using Distribution

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm using Cordova PhoneGap for iOS. Everything works fine in device. When i use archive for app store, in Project setting i used duplicate of release and change to Distribution. I'm getting linker error. When i remove the Distribution the archive is working. Is i need to set Distribution? or release is enough? I'm getting below error while using Distribution:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/gv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/peeq-gylybvwifdxjmtajtbvdsdpjcvkl/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/gv/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libCordova.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13883471/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-not-found-when-archiving-for-distribution

Comment: If i use Distribution this error coming. If i use release it doesn't come. Is Distribution need?

Comment: No, you should use release.

Comment: If i use release the error is not coming..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to duplicate the release settings and rename it to Distribution. Just use release and it is fine to upload to the App Store.