# Xcode, Git, Jenkins, PhoneGap 1.5.0 Build Error

Tags: ios, xcode, git, cordova, jenkins

I have developed an application with phonegap 1.5.0 previously and now we just pushed into git repository. The app was build successfully in xCode and I was able to install the app and run it on the iPad but when we tried to build it from Jenkins, we got this error

```
/Users/...../Classes/AppDelegate.m:28:
/Users/......./Classes/AppDelegate.h:31:13: fatal error: 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
```

I really don't know why is this happening. Did I not include any file into gitt that causes this problem? or is there any extra steps that I need to take to put the codes into git? Any advice on this is deeply appreciated.

Comment: @Amanda Could you solve it? If yes, please post the solution as Answer. I am facing the same problem.

Comment: Hi Apurv... Sorry for the late reply... I cannot say that I solved it but, how I got my ios to work in Jenkins is by upgrading the cordova library to 2.2.0. then it works :)

Answer (score 3):

My PhoneGap project is able to build and generates .ipa.

Here's what I have done for my CI integration using Jenkins:

1. Install Xcode integration plugin for Jenkins (manage Jenkins --> Manage Plugins --> Available --> Xcode integration).
2. In your Job configuration, click the Add build Step button and choose Xcode.
3. In Xcode configuration:

   3.1. Add Clean before build.

   3.2. Add Target of your project (e.g.: SamplePhonegap).

   3.3. Add SDK (e.g.: iphoneos6.1).

   3.4. Add Configuration as Debug or Release.

   3.5. Add Xcode Project Directory which contain .xcodeproj (e.g.: ${WORKSPACE}).

   3.6. Build output directory (e.g.: ${WORKSPACE}/build) [Mandatory Step for PhoneGap App].

   3.7. Add Build IPA.

   3.8. Add Code Signing Identity (e.g.: iPhone Developer: S***** ****** (6********)).

   3.9. Add Unlock KeyChain.

   3.10. Add keyChain Path (e.g.: ${HOME}/Library/Keychains/login.keychain).

   3.11. Add Keychain password.

Finally build your app - it will build and generate the .ipa file.

**Note:**

3.6 step is mandatory because a PhoneGap project has two build paths: one is our project build path and another one is cordova build path. Jenkins tough to find the path default (In native not need to specify, because it has only one build path Jenkins can easily find). So it's mandatory to provide Build output directory path.

Comment: ${WORKSPACE}/build is what fixed this for me!

Comment: How to use if I m using shell script for build process using xcodebuild and xcrun.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to try to clone the git repo to your local machine and build from there. If it's ok, it means that you need to check Jenkins setting/configuration.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening. My cordova library is not placed physically in the project folder. Do you think that this is the cause that the file could not be found? Maybe after placing it in the physical file it will solve the problem? Or do I need to do any special configuration in xcode to place the file into the project folder?

Comment: Normally you can just drag from finder into xcode to include that to the project.

Answer (score 0):

This by far the best solution i found.[Original Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12596916/2129172)

**Xcode 6.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

**Xcode 7.x**

add `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include` to BuildSettings->Header Search Paths

1.Double click the  and you can add this in.

2.Change $(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include to `$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include`