# still getting <Cordova/CDVViewController.h> file not found error in xcode

Tags: xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new in PhoneGap, making a app via Xcode; But I found an error regarding `CDVViewController.h`. However, the file physically exists there. I am using Xcode 4.6 and Cordova 2.2.0.

Comment: "X-Code"? And you still there? Pfff...

Comment: @H2CO3 It's better than I-pad, right?

Comment: @Undo Let's say I can't decide which one is worse.

Comment: What is the exact error you get?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios/12596916#12596916

Answer (score 16):

Man, there are a lot of red herring answers to this question out there. This is what worked for me, and is in the documentation for both PhoneGap 2.5 and 3.0 (see here: [PhoneGap docs for iOS (look under "missing headers")](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_ios_index.md.html#iOS%20Platform%20Guide), using Xcode 4.6.

1. In Xcode, go to Preferences... > Locations, then click on the Advanced... button.
2. Make sure the build location radio button is set to "Unique".
3. Close out the Preferences and Rebuild.

Comment: This one worked for me, after having tried a ton of alternatives.

Comment: Well, that was a red herring for me.

Comment: In all seriousness, though - this is still a common configuration problem and is still listed up on the iOS platform guide as of Oct 2015. I run into it periodically when I switch between mobile (iOS) and desktop development and forget to change the build locations.

Comment: I would give you 5 starts not one for this. Thanks

Comment: Wow - an hour trying the other solutions. This one did it. XCode version 7.3.1 - Cordova version 6.2.0 Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

Please add this line to your projects **Build Settings >> Header Search Paths**:

```
$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/$(PLATFORM_NAME)/include
```

it's worked on **Xcode 7.0 + and iOS 9+**.

[image]

Comment: Thanx :-) This happen due the latest upgrade to iOS9 (and the latest xCode update)

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you're building to the local build output directory, rather than the new xcode artefact store, you may need to copy the contents of CordovaLib/build into $YOURPROJECT/build.

The same applies if you're using xcodebuild from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your CordovaLib sub-project reference.

1. Launch Terminal.app
2. Go to the location where you installed Cordova in the **bin** sub-folder. For example, /Users/Shared/Cordova/phonegap-2.2.0/lib/ios/bin
3. Run the script below where the first parameter is the path to your project's .xcodeproj file:

   `./update_cordova_subproject path/to/your/project/xcodeproj`

Answer (score -2):

```
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" "$(OBJROOT)/UninstalledProducts/include" "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/usr/local/lib/include"
```

phonegap add podfile must include above