# Cannot archive and create ipa file in Cordova project

Tags: cordova, xcode7, ipa

Recently upgraded to XCode 7.1 but now unable to archive and create ipa file. Its a Cordova based project and following is the error message while archiving:

> 'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found

However the same code is working in previous XCode and archiving is working as well. What could be done to fix this issue?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12184767/phonegap-cdvviewcontroller-h-file-not-found-when-archiving-for-ios/12596916#12596916

Comment: @Mulhoon oh great. Thanks for the link.